# spark maven dependency understanding

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I am trying to understand how spark works with Maven ,
I have the following question : Do I need to have spark installed in my machine to build spark application ( in scala ) with maven ? 
Or should I just add the spark dependency into the POM.xml of my  maven project

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. At build time you all your dependencies will be collected by Maven or Sbt. There is no need for an additional Spark installation.

Also at runtime (an this might also include the execution of unit test during the build) you do not necessarily need a Spark installation. If the value of `SPARK_HOME` is not set to a valid Spark installation, default values will be used for the [runtime configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) of Spark.

However, as soon as you want to start Spark jobs on a remote cluster (by using `spark-submit`) you will need a Spark installation.

Comment: great , thanks for your answer , is it the same for sbt ?

Comment: thanks for these details , the spark installation will be needed for the remote cluster not my local machine , let's suppose that I am running spark jobs via spark submiet with yarn as RM and using cluster mode , in this case no spark for my local machine , but spark required for the different nodes of the cluster ?

Comment: no, for the submit to the yarn cluster you will need in most cases a local spark installation

Comment: ok so If I package my saprk application into a jar , copy this jar into the cluster , and do the spark submit in a node from an edge node (via an oozie webservice) I guess that spark installatio will be needed for this case in the edge node ?

Comment: yes. If you have a Spark installation on the edge node, you even dont have to package Spark into your application

Comment: I will package my application for the spark dependency I will define its scope as provided in the pom.xml .

Comment: so if I understood you whenever I need to launch job spark with spark submit , spark binaries are mandatory for the node in which I am doing thr saprk submit command ? May you confirm this please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170810/discussion-between-werner-and-ben).

Comment: yes, you are right. I have opened a chat for further discussion